# div tags in one line with the decorating underline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set three div tags to be in one line and get separated  by some spaces and different underline colors. to make things easier, this is what I'm trying to do:[image]

see posted in Tech and share and tweet. that's what I'm trying to do. I saw their source code, and tried to imitate. but failed. can you please help me?

```
<div class="source">
    <a href="#"><h3>source</h3></a>
</div>
<div class="share">
    <h3>share</h3>
</div>
<div class="share">
    <h3>tweet</he>
</div>
```

Comment: add css like this  share{border-bottom: 1px solid red;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove inline style and add class in stylesheet:

```
<div style="float:left; border-bottom:2px solid #1D1D1B; width:48%; margin-right:2%"><a href="#">POSTED IN TECH</a>
</div>
<div style="float:left; border-bottom:2px solid #FB473A; width:23%; margin-right:2%;">SHARE
</div>
<div style="float:left; border-bottom:2px solid #FB473A; width:23%;  margin-right:2%;">TWEET
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this works great. but only problem is it needs margin between it's top and bottom, right now mine looks like this;http://imgur.com/n7uNlT9...I tried margin-top and bott0m:2%; but it messes up the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

```css
div
{
  display:inline-block;
  }
.source
{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  }
.share
{
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="source">
    <a href="#"><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</h3></a>
</div>
<div class="share">
    <h3>share</h3>
</div>
<div class="share">
    <h3>tweet</he>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flexbox;` to center items in the same row, `border-bottom` to get the colored lines, and `margin-right` for spacing.

```css
.source, .share{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    width:100%;  
    margin-right:5px;
}
.source a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
.source h3,.share h3{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.share{
    border-bottom:2px solid red;  
}
.source{
    border-bottom:2px solid gray;  
}
.flex{
    display:flex; 
    width:100%;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<div class="source">
    <a href="#"><h3>source</h3></a>
</div>
<div class="share">
    <h3>share</h3>
</div>
<div class="share">
    <h3>tweet</he>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you have in your screen shot, Keep HTML whatever you already posted and write CSS for them as below. (Change color and width as you prefer)

```
.source {border-bottom:2px solid #000; width:48%; padding-bottom:10px; margin-right:2%}
.share {border-bottom:2px solid #d90000; width:23%; padding-bottom:10px; margin-right:2%}
.share:nth-child(2) {margin-right:0}
```

Regards

Manoj Soni